# git: how to rebase before HEAD

Tags: git, git-rebase

I don't know much how to use rebase, but it seems the rebase only change the starting point to a more recent commit

in my case I did stuff on branch *test* that was pushed, another person pulled the changes B to E
In the mean time I changed slightly a commit, and I deleted (bad idea) my remote branch to recreate one with the same commits

so because of this now it looks after a merge:

```
A---B---C---D---E--F--G--H  master
 \--B'--C'--D'--E'/    test
```

B and B' are the same, at same time, same commit message..., C, C' also, ..D and D' , E and E'

Is there other solution than git rebase -i, I tried it but you lose other branches merge history

I would actually like to remove B, C, D, E, Is it possible if the branches are already merged?

I have no right to push on remote master, only pulling

I tried pruning but those unecessary commits are not removed since they point to others
I would really like to rebase master A onto master E', if it's possible

thx for tips

**edit** : else, how could a person with push right could fix permanently that situation?

I can fix this by

```
git reset --hard A
git pull repo1 test (where test still is at E')
git rebase --onto F A master
```

but if the admin pulls it, I guess it will have no effect?, he should do this manip himself right before any other user pull from this mess?

Comment: How did you push those changes in the first place if you have no push access?

Comment: sry: I pushed them on repo1 test, the admin pulled them in origin master, and when I pull again from origin master I saw this %!#

Comment: You could use rebase to fix up commits locally, and probably even a force push to repo1; however, the admin will have to do some work to clean up *origin/master*.  If he does that, it'll create work for anyone else who branched from *origin/master* to get their branches sorted out (if any were made after commit A).

Comment: well it's not too late, no1 should have pulled yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get rid of that unwanted merge at F would be to [create a grafts file](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) and put there a line `<hash of F> <hash of E'>` Then check with gitk that the history looks like you want it. If all looks file, the next step is to make that graft permanent by rewriting the recent commits: `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- <hash of A>..master` Finally force-push the rewritten commits to the repository with `git push -f`

Comment: perfect! but how will this deal with other users when they will pull me again? because I'v read git rebase, and it's clearly said an already pushed branch shouldn't be rebased

Comment: And do I have to keep that .git/info/grafts file forever? I guess it's no longer needed after the filter branch @Esko

Comment: After filter-branch the grafts file is not anymore needed.

Comment: If some other users already pulled some of those commits which are rewritten, then they will need to do a `git reset --hard` or clone the repository again. If they did some commits, then they will need to rebase them or do this same trick.

Comment: It's perfectly working locally, I forced pushed it on my branch, but unfortunately, when other has merged again my branch, it's still with 5 double entries on origin/master, I would need to do this 2 step trick on the master remote master repo.. but can't